# Filter events in calendar for ruby on rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I ve used the `fullcalendar assets` gem for listing out all the events in the calendar, i have tried to modify the calendar as per my needs but for this scenario i am getting confused.
Ive used https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar

**Scenario:**
I have to filtered out all the appointments in the calendar for a particular worker. so in my appointments controller ive listed all the appointments in this way.

```
@appointments = @client.appointments
```

and it is listing all the appointments of a client, so now i ve to again filter out the appointments based on the selection of drop down button where i am listing all the workers of the client. so based on the worker selected, it will show the appointments of that particular selected worker.

**Code tried**

**1. Rails Way**

First i ve tried in the rails way that i needed to pass the `id` of the worker from the drop down to the controller, the code for drop down i ve used:

```
<%= form_tag appointments_path do %>
    <%= select_tag(:worker_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@client.workers, :id, :alias), :include_blank =>true)%>
    <%=submit_tag "Display"%>
<% end %>
```

But i dont know what to pass in the controller for fetching the records.

**2. JS way**

```
<%= select_tag(:worker_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@client.workers, :id, :alias), :include_blank =>true),:onchange => 'a(this.value)'%>
```

**calendar.js**

```
function a(pointer){
var intWorkerId = pointer;
alert(intWorkerId);
$.ajax({
    url:'/appointments',
    dataType: "json",
    data:({
            id:intWorkerId
        }),
    type:'get',
    success:function(result){

        alert(result);
        $('#content').html(result);
                console.log(1);
  }
});
}
```

Some how the id of a worker i am getting in the controller as i ve tried to print the value and tried also to print the values from that id and it is correct but i dont know how to proceed.

**Appointment.rb**

```
def as_json(options = {})
{
  :id => self.id,
  :title => self.title,
  :description => self.description || "",
  :start => appointment_start_time.rfc822,
  :end => appointment_end_time.rfc822,
  :allDay => self.all_day,
  :recurring => false,
  :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.appointment_path(id)
  #:color => "red"
}
```

**Appointment_controller.rb**

```
if params[:id]
  #@appointments = @client.workers.params[:id].appointments
  #p "*********id values****#{params[:id]}"
  #worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
  #p"***** #{worker.alias}"
  #@appointments = worker.appointments
  #p "******* #{@appointments.count}"
  p "*******hello id is here*******"
else
  @appointments = "hello"
  p "*******hello id is not here*******"
end
```

I ve tried every possible combination but not able to get results. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If appointments is an association on Worker you can get the clients worker like this:

```
@worker = @client.workers.find(params[:id])
```

The get that worker's appointments:

```
@appointments = @worker.appointments
```

This is assuming that in your Appointment class you have:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
end
```

And your Worker:

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
end
```

In your controller you also need to get the @client. How are you currently doing that? Is it `current_user`? If not you need to pass in the client id in your form:

```
<%= form_tag appointments_path do %>
    <%= select_tag(:worker_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@client.workers, :id, :alias), :include_blank =>true)%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :client_id, session[:client_id] # or wherever you store this
    <%=submit_tag "Display"%>
<% end %>
```

Now you can find the client in your controller:

```
@client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
```

Also note that in the example form you provided you're passing the id of the worker as `:worker_id`, so you need to use `params[:worker_id]` in your controller. The JS example you provided uses `:id` so I'm assuming that's the approach you're going with since you use params[:id] in your controller example.

Finally, return the appointments as a JSON array:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:id]
      @appointments = @client.workers.find(params[:id])
      render json: @appointments.map(&:as_json)
    else
      @appointments = "hello"
      p "*******hello id is not here*******"
    end
```

Comment: i worked with this.. and it is saying parameter missing.. and i dont know why it is going to `appointmentscontroller#create`.

Comment: It's going there because appointments_path is being passed to form_tag. I'm not sure why it says parameter missing, are you using Rails4 strong parameters? What line is throwing that error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by `re-rendering` the calendar once again in the same `js file`

```
function RenderCalendar(eId) {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    aspectRatio: 1.5,   
    slotMinutes: 30,
    slotEventOverlap: true,
    editable: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',                             // September 2009
        week: "| MMM d[ yyyy] { '&#8212;' MMM d | yyyy}", // |Sep 7 - Sep 13|, 2009
        day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'                  // Tuesday, Sep 8, 2009
    },

 events: {
        url: '/appointments',
        cache: true,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: eId
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
    },
```